# Como proceder regressão não linear pelo modelo mitscherlich?

Tags: r, regressão

Olá, boa tarde!

preciso realizar uma análise de regressão não linear `nls()`, e me sugeriram o modelo mitscherlich:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei como realizar, gostaria da ajuda de vocês!

segue exemplo dos dados:

```
dados<-structure(list(TEMPO = c(4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 
15, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 30, 30, 30, 35, 35, 35, 40, 40, 40
), COM = c(102.7408349, 46.42860925, 46.42860925, 193.9867874, 
77.78158526, 77.78158526, 259.2226911, 142.9585464, 142.9585464, 
338.2513753, 201.6268249, 201.6268249, 540.8096753, 230.0649675, 
230.0649675, 621.6945295, 243.5781577, 356.2446836, 678.4896365, 
303.6745224, 532.1778946, 731.7253377, 317.1877126, 621.6366503, 
794.4532011, 353.1853056, 688.7228286)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 82:108)
```

Comment: Um primeiro passo é rodar `?nls` dentro do console do R. Veja os exemplos de uso da função e, caso não entenda algo, edite a sua pergunta com sua dúvida.

Comment: não consigo rodar nls(), normalmente sempre pede chutes iniciais, e não sei como colocar essa fórmula dentro da função nls(), aparentemente alfa significa o valor máximo esperado, como não existe, estou utilizando o máximo encontrado, gama seria "b" não sei ao certo, e theta pelo pouco que consegui entender tem haver com a inclinação da reta (nem sei se é uma reta), vi vários trabalhos que utilizam o modelo porém não explicam como utilizam :/ gostaria de ajuda! a variável x é o "TEMPO", e a variável resposta é "COM". Os valores reference à total de carbono orgânico mineralizado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O ajuste não é bom mas segue:

```
fm <- nls(COM ~ Alfa*(1-10^(-Gama*(TEMPO+Tetha))),
                 data = dados,
                 start = list(Alfa = 900, Gama = .1, Tetha = 1))
summary(fm)

# Parameters:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# Alfa   1.785e+03  3.844e+03   0.464    0.647
# Gama   4.703e-03  1.265e-02   0.372    0.713
# Tetha -6.293e-01  4.629e+00  -0.136    0.893

plot(COM~TEMPO,dados)
lines(dados$TEMPO,predict(fm),col=3)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O ajuste não é assim tão mau quanto isso, `hist(resid(fm))` dá gaussiano.

Comment: Nesse caso como devo proceder infelizmente não tenho conhecimento estatístico sobre análises não lineares :/

Comment: Esses dados são reais, são várias medições por período? A análise do modelo é similar aos outros modelos lineares

Comment: esses dados são apenas um desmembramento de um fatorial 3, o tempo ai representa dias de inoculação, quando se roda, a anova para fatorial 3, o ajuste tende para uma regressão quadrática, com platô, por isso segundo ela sua orientadora, que não é da área de estatística solicitou uma ajuste para um modelo de distribuição assintótica, indicando o de  mitscherlich, que viu que o Pimentel-Gomes apresenta no livro: Estatística Aplicada a experimentos agropecuários e Florestais.

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a equação escrita por [@Robert](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/384870/149176), o exemplo abaixo adiciona a curva usando a função `geom_smooth()` do pacote `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(dados, aes(TEMPO, COM))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "nls",
              formula = y~Alfa*(1-10^(-Gama*(x+Tetha))),
              method.args = list(start = c(Alfa = 900, Gama = .1, Tetha = 1)),
              data=dados,
              se=F)
```